# Get Pidgin Logs From Other Directory

Tags: windows, linux, dropbox, pidgin

I'm using Pidgin on both Windows and Linux on several PCs. To sync my log, I use Dropbox. For Linux, it's easy. Just a matter of a symlink. However, I don't know how to sync it on Windows without manual copy-paste once I'm done.

So, is there any solution to my problem? Pidgin plugin, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows also supports [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link), though they are sparsely documented. They work only if you're on Windows Vista, 7 or above.

Comment: Lucky I'm on windows 7. I'll read it.

Answer (score 1):

The OP reported that, inspired by [MDMarra’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/249203/354511#249228),
they did this to solve their problem:

- Back up and delete the current log (it's located at
  `C:\Users\{your user name}\AppData\Roaming\.purple\logs`)
- `mklink /D "C:\Users\{your user name}\AppData\Roaming\.purple\logs" "E:\My Dropbox\somepath\purplelogs"`
  (all on one line)

  - `"C:\Users\{your user name}\AppData\Roaming\.purple\logs"` is where you want your symlink at
  - `"E:\My Dropbox\somepath\purplelogs"` is where you have your *dropboxed* logs.